# Java Equivalent OpenCV Code to this C++ Code

Tags: image-processing, overlay, opencv3.0, alphablending

Can anybody tell me the correct java code for this c++ code snippet:

> output.at(x, y) = target.at(dx, dy);

I have tried this java code and they are displacing pixel but not showing image clearly :

> output.put(x, y, target.get(dx, dy));

Answer (score 0):

**For one channel images e.g. grey-scale; 0 ~ 255**

Getting a pixel value

```
double pixelValue = image.get(i,j)[0];
```

Setting a pixel value

```
image.put(i,j,230);
```

**For 3 channel images e.g. RGB (3 values 0 ~ 255)**

Getting a pixel (*double[] array will have 3 values*)

```
double[] pixelValue = image.get(i,j);
```

Setting a pixel with 3 RGB values

```
image.put(i,j,255,250,100); // yellow color
```

Comment: sorry i'm newbie to opencv and image processing but here i am reciveing error :Provided data element number (1) should be multiple of the Mat channels count (4)

Comment: good it's start working, can you please tell me how to set this :  output.put(y, x, ((backgroundPx * (1. - opacity)) + (foregroundPx * opacity)));

Comment: What is your error/problem you are facing? Also, please consider setting my answer as 'accepted'.